# Matlab 2012a installation ubuntu 12.02 issue

Tags: installation, matlab

I'm trying to install MATLAB2012 on my Ubuntu machine, and, in order to do that I have to give the installation program the root rights, this is what  I've tried :

```
root@Engine:/media/ENGINE# ./install
bash: ./install: Permission denied
```

I've tried also gsku :

```
root@Engine:/media/ENGINE# gksu ./install
```

Nothing happens.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still get the `Permission denied` message when you try to run something while you are root, this means that the program you are trying to run doesn't have the executable bit, and thus it isn't allowed to run as program, it is consider as a simple file by the system.

The `gksu` you gave there while you were root wouldn't solve any problem, you were `root`, and `root` is allowed to do anything.

So, in order to give it the executable bit:

```
chmod +x install
```

Now, the system recognizes that the file 'install' is not a simple file, but it is actually a program. After that, you can successfully run:

```
./install
```

And you should be OK :)

PS: I myself remember, when I was not used to Linux as well, to be very confused by this `Permission denied` message while I was root. I mean, I was root, who denies me to do anything ? I am the lord of this land :P

Comment: engine@Engine:/media/ENGINE$ sudo su
    [sudo] password for engine: 
    root@Engine:/media/ENGINE# chmod +x install
    root@Engine:/media/ENGINE# ./install
    bash: ./install: Permission denied <code>

Comment: Oh, now I see, the executable is at an external media, copy the installation files to your local hard disk in order to install! This is because non-extX file systems do not allow the executable bit to be placed to the files... So move your files inside your hard disk and try chmod +x again.

Comment: thanks for your help hakermania: but it didn't work.

engine@Engine:~/GOOD/MATLAB$ sudo su

[sudo] password for engine: 

root@Engine:/home/engine/GOOD/MATLAB# chmod +x install
root@Engine:/home/engine/GOOD/MATLAB# ./install
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
./install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_8262/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished

Comment: sorry I don't know how to write code format here

Answer (score 1):

You can also try
`sh ./install` on the media (if you are the root/superuser) or `sudo sh ./install`

Comment: thanks Marius,
it worked but I got the same Java error

Comment: @Engine what "Java" error are you getting?

Comment: ./install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_8461/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished

Comment: Me too. Did you solve it? (chmodding sys/java/.../java from install dir doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

> Matlab 2012a Installation Instructions
>
> You will need superuser privileges. The assumption is that MATLAB
>   install files are located at `/media/MATHWORKS_R2011a` in your
>   filesystem.
>
> Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your
>   keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, Run the MATLAB installer
>   with the following Terminal command:
>
> ```
> sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2011A/install
> ```
>
> When prompted to 'Choose installation type' you should select custom.
>   This will allow you to create symbolic links to MATLAB in
>   `/usr/local/bin`.<sup>1</sup>

[Read on](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

so I got it, the first problem with the file install is was solved, with both solutions :

```
chmod +x install
./install
```

and also from the media like Marius suggested :    sudo sh ./install.

for the Java installation error : I had to make an excutable bit for java file under : 
*MATLAB/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin*